# .co TLD domains do not resolve while others do

Tags: centos, resolve, djbdns

I'm running LAMP with Interworx CP. its on a Centos 6.4 box and the DNS Interworx installed is DJBDNS 1.05.

I have multiple domains "hosted" on the box, some .com, some .org, and some .net. When attempting to add two .co domains, the .co tld domains will not resolve. In order for them to show up I am have add the zones at my register instead of within Interworx. This leads my to think its an issues with DJBDNS. After searching I cannot find anything that confirms my thinking. Any ideas?

`dig +trace o.co` output:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.6 <<>> +trace o.co
;; global options: +cmd
.                       401922  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       401922  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       401922  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       401922  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       401922  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       401922  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       401922  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       401922  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       401922  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       401922  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       401922  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       401922  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       401922  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
;; Received 449 bytes from 10.255.255.4#53(10.255.255.4) in 1971 ms

co.                     172800  IN      NS      ns1.cctld.co.
co.                     172800  IN      NS      ns5.cctld.co.
co.                     172800  IN      NS      ns2.cctld.co.
co.                     172800  IN      NS      ns4.cctld.co.
co.                     172800  IN      NS      ns6.cctld.co.
co.                     172800  IN      NS      ns3.cctld.co.
;; Received 400 bytes from 2001:dc3::35#53(2001:dc3::35) in 129 ms

o.co.                   900     IN      NS      NS4.P20.DYNECT.NET.
o.co.                   900     IN      NS      NS3.P20.DYNECT.NET.
o.co.                   900     IN      NS      NS2.P20.DYNECT.NET.
o.co.                   900     IN      NS      NS1.P20.DYNECT.NET.
;; Received 108 bytes from 156.154.105.25#53(156.154.105.25) in 1917 ms

o.co.                   7200    IN      A       173.241.154.157
o.co.                   14400   IN      NS      ns3.p20.dynect.net.
o.co.                   14400   IN      NS      ns4.p20.dynect.net.
o.co.                   14400   IN      NS      ns2.p20.dynect.net.
o.co.                   14400   IN      NS      ns1.p20.dynect.net.
;; Received 124 bytes from 2001:500:94:1::20#53(2001:500:94:1::20) in 27 ms
```

Comment: What troubleshooting steps have you done to lead you to believe this is an issue with your name server?

Comment: I've for starters I have multiple domains resolving just fine. if use my registers DNS and add the zones on their servers it works, if I use my servers DNS for the zones it does not work. Since it works when dns is used else where I know its not a vhost config issues with apache. all of this leads me to think its my DNS. it may be a config setting somewhere I dont know about or it may just not support that TLD. Thats why im here.

Comment: Consider grabbing dig (usually in a package called something like bind-tools; you don't need bind for it) and doing a `dig +trace in any co.` to see what you get.

Comment: Updated post with dig output

Comment: djbdns hasn't officially been updated in 13 years. Are you sure that you wan't to use some other software, like BIND?

Comment: I would prefer to use BIND, However since Interworx uses DJBDNS which stores the zones created in the CP into a database I cannot switch to BIND.

Comment: This problem was solved, the problem was caused by an ip gateway issue that was not allowing the djbdns to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved, the problem was caused by an ip gateway issue that was not allowing the djbdns to work properly.